# replace more than one special character with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I´m a nooby in regex so i have my headache with sed.
I need help to replace all special characters from the given company names with "-".

So this is the given string:

```
FML Finanzierungs- und Mobilien Leasing GmbH & Co. KG
```

I want the result:

```
FML-Finanzierungs-und-Mobilien-Leasing-GmbH-&-Co-KG
```

I tried the following:

```
nr = $(echo "$name" | sed -e 's/ /-/g'))
```

so this replace all whitespaces with `-`, but what the right expression to replace the others? My one search via google are not very successful.

Comment: What others character than space do you like to replace? `.`?

Comment: Note also that `nr = $(...)` is wrong. You need to remove the spaces around the `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what you consider to be a special character -- I say this because you appear to consider `&` a regular character but not `.`, which seems a bit odd. Anyway, I imagine something of the form

```
nr=$(echo "$name" | sed 's/[^[:alnum:]&]\+/-/g')
```

would serve you best. Here `[^[:alnum:]&]` matches any character that is not alphanumeric or `&`, and `[^[:alnum:]&]\+` matches a sequence of one or more such characters, so the `sed` call replaces all such sequences in `$name` with a hyphen. If there are other characters that you consider regular, add them to the set. Note that the handling of umlauts and suchlike depends on your locale.

Also note that `echo` *may* cause trouble if `$name` begins with a hyphen (it could be parsed as options for `echo`), so if you can tether yourself to `bash`,

```
nr=$(sed 's/[^[:alnum:]&]\+/-/g' <<< "$name")
```

might be more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you wan to remove `-` and `.` and then replace spaces with `-`.

This would do it, by saying `sed -e 'one thing' -e 'another thing'`:

```
$ echo "$name" | sed -e 's/[-\.]//g' -e 's/ /-/g'
FML-Finanzierungs-und-Mobilien-Leasing-GmbH-&-Co-KG
```

Note we enclose within square backets all the characters that we want to treat equally: `[-\.]` means either `-` or `.` (we need to escape it, otherwise it would match any character).

Answer (score 1):

Do this help you:

```
awk -vOFS=- '{gsub(/[.-]/,"");$1=$1}1' <<< "$name"
FML-Finanzierungs-und-Mobilien-Leasing-GmbH-&-Co-KG
```

`gsub(/[.-]/,"")` Removes `.` and `_`
`-vOFS=-` sets new field separator to `-`
`$1=$1` reconstruct the line so it uses new field separator
`1` print the line.

To get it to a variable

```
nr=$(awk -vOFS=- '{gsub(/[.-]/,"");$1=$1}1' <<< "$name")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way also

```
echo "name" | sed 's/ \|- \|\. /-/g'
```

**OutPut :**

```
FML-Finanzierungs-und-Mobilien-Leasing-GmbH-&-Co-KG
```